# Jquery Change() when not on mouse selection

Tags: jquery

I have a multiple select box, and have some actions associated to it, when selection changes etc. This all works fine when working in a normal way, however, i'm using a jquery widget to make the selection more user friendly. So it clones the data from the original select and then hides it.

If I unhide, i see that the actions in the widget are replicated in the original, which is good. However, my actions were associated to change() on the select don't work anymore. 
I checked the documentation for Jquery and it says:

The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to  elements,  boxes and  elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.

So as it says, when the selection is made with the mouse, it works, and it does. But in this case it all happens in the background. Is there another event handler that i can use, which will monitor changes even when not made by the mouse?

The widget I'm using is this [one](http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect_original/)

This is the code in my js file.

```
    $(".multiselect").live('change', function() {
        $("option", this).each(function() {
                //do something.
        });
    }).trigger('change');
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @mcgrailm: edited question and added some code and the link to the widget used. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use `trigger('change')` as part of your jQuery that causes the selection to change to, as it says, *trigger* the `change` event.

Reference:

- [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/);

Comment: have you tried attaching the `.trigger()` to the `option` that you're changing? `$('option',this).each(function(){/*...*/}).trigger('change');`

Comment: Thanks, i've just tried and it didn't work. I think it shouldn't anyway, no? As the main function would not be triggered anyway, so it wouldn't even get to the inner code. In any case, it would see using the 'change' event would not work, as the change is not made with the mouse as per documentation.

Comment: Can you reproduce this on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so that we can see what you're working with? Or, at least, a minimal demo that reproduces your problem.